# Check if the clicked div id matches with variable

Tags: jquery, variables, if-statement, variable-assignment

I'm a coding newbie and looking for a way to check in jQuery whether the name of a certain variable corresponds to the ID of a div, and if so fire some code. Unfortunately, something about my syntax is off, and I can't figure out what.

For a simple example, I want to click a div and store the ID of the div as a variable, and if I click it again the variable gets cleared. Simply assigning another boolean variable is not possible due to the rest of the code, I require the ID-check-thingy or something similar.

This is what I have got so far:

```
<div class="testdiv" id="primary">Bananarama</div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".testdiv").click(function() {
        if ($(this).attr("id") == "#" + clickedElement) {     
            // if the ID of the clicked div matches the variable, proceed. This is the part that doesn't seem to work
            alert ("Victory"); // display alert so we know everything worked out
            var clickedElement = null; // reset the variable
        } else {
            var clickedElement = $(this).attr("id"); // the div has been clicked, assign its ID to the variable
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use directly compare your variable with `this.id`

```
if(this.id == clickedElement)
```

However I would recommend you to use [`.is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/)

```
if($(this).is('#' + clickedElement))
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var clickedElement;
  $(".testdiv").click(function() {
    if (this.id == clickedElement) {
      // if the ID of the clicked div matches the variable, proceed. This is the part that doesn't seem to work
      alert("Victory"); // display alert so we know everything worked out
      clickedElement = null; // reset the variable
    } else {
      clickedElement = this.id; // the div has been clicked, assign its ID to the variable
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="testdiv" id="primary">Bananarama</div>
```

Comment: hmmm... unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work. If I add another alert in the else-part of the loop, it seems it's stuck there?

Comment: @Jokes_on_me, Define `var clickedElement` in global scope. Updated answer with snippet

Comment: That undeniably works, thanks a lot! May I ask you what defining the     var clicked Element in global scope changes here? (Never mind if the answer is complicated)

Comment: @Jokes_on_me it's about variable scope. The variable doesn't exist outside event handler. Hence the value is not persisted.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 issues in your code:

1) You don't need extra ID selector in if comparison here. `.attr("id")` returns ID of element and not selector for it.

2) You don't need to re-declare variable inside if and else condition. due to redefining the variable in those conditions are restricting its scope inside that particluar condition only.

Also you should minimize recreation of jquery object for target element. Its always a good practice to create it once and then re use it further:

```
var $this = $(this);
var clickedElement;
if ($this.attr("id") == clickedElement) {     // if the ID of the clicked div matches the variable, proceed. This is the part that doesn't seem to work
        alert ("Victory");     // display alert so we know everything worked out
        clickedElement = null;     // reset the variable
} else {
        clickedElement = $this.attr("id");     // the div has been clicked, assign its ID to the variable
}
```