# Checking if currently clicked element is equal to a specific div 'id' in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

I have researched on the web and tested for a solution for quite a while, but have not been able to make this work. So I have decided to create a post here, even though its probably low-skilled and I'll get downvoted for it I have put a lot of effort and I hope someone can help out.

My code at the moment uses `.click()` function from JQuery and my goal is to use it on a button so that when I click that button, it checks whether the `id` of the button clicked on matches a variable that I set in the `.js` file. In other words, check if the thing I clicked on's `id` is equal to my "target".

This is the part of the code with the problem:

```
var target = '#vig_but_inc';

$(this).click(function() {

    if(this.id == target) {
        vigor.incStat(); // increase stats once
        console.log("hi"); // test if code fires
        $('#vig_res').html(vigor.current);
    }
});
```

Please note I have checked if the code works without matching the `id`, without the `if`-statement - in that situation if I click on a specific, preset button's `id` I managed to increase the value of `#vig_res` which is my goal.

However with the `if` involved, as explained prior, *I am trying to match what is being clicked on with my `target`*, which is the `id` name I wish it to match to. I'm using `this` to check my click, which has worked in other areas but doesn't seem to work in this context.

I have made the variable target global scope as explained here in the comments: [Check if the clicked div id matches with variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41165653/check-if-the-clicked-div-id-matches-with-variable). It still doesn't work.

I know and have tested `$(this).click(..`, where it would fire off the code inside of whatever `div` I clicked. So I believe the problem lies afterwards, maybe in the `this.id`, but I've also used `.is()` like suggested elsewhere but it won't work that way either.

I hope someone can give me some insight into how to tackle this problem, thank you.

Comment: debug by checking what does `this.id` give you

Comment: What does `this` refer in `$(this).click()`? Learn to use `console`

Comment: @Satpal I believe I learned this makes the currently clicked on event fire the `.click()` function on that, I've tried it works as long as I'm not trying to match `this.id`. My goal of this code is simply to check if what I clicked on is my pre-set `id`, if it is, fire the code inside the function.

Comment: I'm not so sure abstracting the button clicks to their IDs is worthwhile.  Why not just define a function that updates vigor when you click the button, ie $('#vig_but_inc').click(function that updates vigor with no "if" that checks what id the clicked button has);

Comment: Also what is the $(this) to which you are assigning the event handler, the document?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is a little more complicated, in the anonymous function which is called when the click is triggered, `this` is not the clicked element, it is a jQuery object. You should accept as first parameter `event` and use `event.target`. Plus, `target` should not contain the `#`, because the `.id` returns only the name.

So, your code should look like this:

```
var target = 'vig_but_inc';

$(this).click(function(event) {
    console.log(event.target);
    if(event.target.id == target) {
        vigor.incStat(); // increase stats once
        console.log("hi"); // test if code fires
        $('#vig_res').html(vigor.current);
    }
});
```

Working Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/e8np0g9j/3/

Comment: Thank you but I don't see how that fiddle shows it "works", if I click on the text (the div) nothing happens). I changed some of the code so that something would appear if it detects a click and goes past the if statement to test but nothing appeared. Could you kindly recheck for me and give a fiddle with an example where clicking passes the `if` statement and something changes in the output?

Comment: ok great it is working! I see you use in the `if` statement `event.target.id` - why is it event.target and not `.this`? In other words, target is a variable we created at the top, why are we comparing the event of this with itself? How can I use this function to match another target, do I have to change this to `event.target2.id == target2`?

Comment: `event` is an Event object. You can read more about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event. `event.target` is not referring to the `target` you have declared. `event.target` is a key on the `event` object. If you want to compare with `target2`, you should simply `event.target.id == target2`.

Comment: @Andrici_Cezar Ok I solved my confusion now, basically you wrote "`event.target.id`", I confused and thought the `target` in that line is the same target as our `var target = 'vig_but_inc';`!! But its just part of the `event` functions I think. Thank you for your help, really appreciate it.

Comment: @Darkphoton no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use the id and class selected before calling the click function like

```
$('.class').click(function() {});
```

Comment: Wow! Really...?